# What is the default implementation of `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`?

Tags: python, object, python-internals

I want to override `__setattr__` and `__getattr__`, but in order to make sure I'm not missing any fields I should update I'd like to know what the default implementation of these methods are. What is the default implementation of these methods?

Comment: Depending on what you want, can you simple call the base method then do what you have to do?

Comment: Usually, you'll just call `super().__getattr__` and `super().__setattr__`, but this depends on what exactly your overrides are supposed to do: *augment* or *change* the default implementation?

Comment: Note, there *is no default implementation of `__getattr__`*.

Comment: Note they are asymmetric: `__getattr__` is only called if the normal mechanism (defined by `__getattribute__`) fails to find an attribute, while `__setattr__` is *always* called (but the default behavior defined by `object.__setattr__` is so fundamental, being supplied by the implementation itself, that asking what it does won't help you override it successfully. You can't say much more than "it creates/modifies an attribute").

Comment: @martineau: to be fair, the documentation isn't always 100% clear about everything. It explains what "normal mechanism" means for ```__setattr__``` but not for ```__getattr__```. What some see as obvious isn't obvious to others.

Comment: @sj95126: That's why I asked what was unclear.

Comment: In cpython, the fundamental objects are written in C and getattr is whatever is in [`PyTypeObject.tp_getattro`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_getattro). A good candidate for a generic implementation is `GenericGetAttrWithDict` found in [`object.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/object.c).

Comment: My intention is to support a class that takes in a dictionary in constructor, and then the `__getattr__` method would look in that dictionary, and then if not found fall back to the object's internal `__dict__` through a super call to `__getattr__`. Similarly, `__setattr__` would modify the passed in dict if the key was there, otherwise fall back. I just wanted to make sure I knew what the base ones were doing to know if this was all allowable.